# React props.children is not rerendering after first state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem I can't seem to be able to figure out.

Container.jsx

```
  const [selectedCardTypeList, setSelectedCardTypeList] = useState([]);

  const onDragEnd = result => {

    const {destination, source, draggableId} = result;
    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }

    if (destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
        destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return;
    }

    let newInputIds = inputs;
    newInputIds.splice(source.index, 1);
    newInputIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);
    setSelectedCardTypeList(newInputIds);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
          <DroppableWrapper selectedCardTypeList={selectedCardTypeList}>
            {selectedCardTypeList.map((v, index) =>
                  <CardContainer removeCardType={removeCardType} cardType={v} index={index}/>
            )}
          </DroppableWrapper>
        </DragDropContext>
      </div>
  )
```

DropableWrapper.jsx

```
import {Droppable} from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import React from "react";

export const DroppableWrapper = ({children, selectedCardTypeList}) => {
  return (
      <>
      <Droppable droppableId="droppable" direction="horizontal">
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <div
                className={selectedCardTypeList.length ? 'container-horizontal' : 'container-vertical'}
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                {...provided.droppableProps}
            >
              {children}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
            )}
      </Droppable>
        </>
)};

export default DroppableWrapper;
```

As you can see I omitted quite a lot of the code, and this is a dummy example but basically what is happening is if I declaratively pass in the children to the parent (using .map), the Child elements will only respect the first state change and despite I can confirm on action the state is being updated, this is not being reflected when rendering {children}.

Any ideas? Thank you!

There is nothing wrong with CardContainer, If I don't abstract the Droppable out as a wrapper just leave it with the container it works.

Comment: show us where you update the state

Comment: The `useState` hook can't "see" if the contents of an array have changed. You should use the `useReducer` hook instead.

Comment: So I omitted quite a lot of code, I am using react beautiful DnD and the state is updated in the onDragEnd prop. I can confirm the state is being updated correctly, I console.log-ed it out and inspected with the React extension. If I move the mapping to the child component, everything works fine, so I can only assume it's a React specific problem I am facing when dynamically passing down props.children.

Comment: Every component created by the map function must have a unique key, this is how React tracks the changes, try to add key={index} to your Child tag inside the map call

Comment: @HermitCrab thanks for your input, I am afraid that was the first thing I tried, but no joy.

Comment: I'm confused. `children` inside a component is *that component's* children. `<Child />` doesn't have any children; it's a self-closing tag.

Comment: I would like to see where you update the state using customState

Comment: @DaveNewton why would Child need to have a children? Child is the children, dynamically mapped. I added the actual code, hope it makes more sense.

Comment: @O.o added the code in context, hope it helps

Comment: let newInputIds = inputs; where is this `inputs` from?

Comment: inputs is just an array.

export const inputs = [
  'date',
  'location'
];

state is updating corretly, there is nothing wrong with that

Comment: The `CardContainer` components should have a key, but importantly: that key must NOT be the array index. Because when you drag things around, as far as React is concerned, the index does not change. The 6th CardContainer will still have key `5` so there's no need to re-render it, even though index 5 now points to a different `v`. Try it with `key={v}`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan you're right with the indexes, being aware of that I tried the array value as a key before posting here, but I've had the same problem. I left it out from my code above, so apologies for that, however it still doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @anddak `<Child />` is the children of `<Parent />`. `children` is the children of the component it's referenced in. The whole point of `children` is to allow a component to wrap its content, e.g., the children of that component. https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891

Comment: Also, you're modifying state directly, which is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @DaveNewton, sorry, I know what you mean. Please ignore the first "example" it's wrong, I haven't realized I've done the example in the wrong way :P Refer to my edit. I am removing those snippets now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the state with a function instead. At the end of `onDragEnd`:

```
    setSelectedCardTypeList(prevState => {
        var newState = [...prevState.slice(0, source.index), ...prevState.slice(source.index + 1)];
        return [...newState(0, destination.index), draggableId, ...newState(destination.index)];
    });
```

Comment: I set the new state with a function like:

    setSelectedCardTypeList(() => {
      return [...newInputIds];
    });

...and it worked. 

Can you please give me context is because of asynchronous operation?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update
You assigned inputs to newInputIds, then modified it. I would guess that react still sees it as the same value.